# Pronouncing compound words treated as one unit

Tags: pronunciation

‎When I say "car door" or "bicycle wheel", compound words treated as one unit, how should I pronounce them? which syllables should I stress?

Comment: Those are not compound words, but syntactic constructions consisting of head +modifier. Compound words are single words, not two separate ones. How the words you cite are pronounced depends on which word is to be stressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single answer to this. Every compound noun may acquire stress in different places, *and* there may be differences between dialects, too!

As a British English speaker, I would emphasise the second word in 'car ***door***', but the first syllable in '***bi***cycle wheel*'.

US English speakers often place emphasis on the first syllable in compound nouns and names where British English speakers would emphasise the last. The example that always strike me is 'Robin Hood', which Americans usually say as '***Rob***in Hood', while the British say 'Robin ***Hood***'

It would be great if there was some single rule that universally governed this, but there isn't. You're just going to have to listen to native speakers.

Comment: I say "ice **cream**", but some (other) British people say "**ice** cream".

Comment: I have been listening to myself saying 'car door', bicycle wheel', and 'ice cream', as well as 'bus ticket', and I honestly can't hear any special emphasis on any of the words.